# Why are there some mini-trucks blasting psy/techno music while driving around Yangon?

Tags: driving, culture, myanmar, music, yangon

I have seen many mini-trucks blasting (> 90 dB) psy/techno music while driving around Yangon with some decent sound system. [Example](https://youtu.be/gCdgRT2f63k?t=13):

[image]

Why are there some mini-trucks blasting psy/techno music while driving around Yangon?

Comment: Seen this in a few places in Asia, it's usually related to local elections. A person who wants to be elected in some sort of office hires people to do this stuff among other things as a part of the campaign. However, I do not see any posters that confirms this in your short video.

Comment: A relevant meta post: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-really-close-curiosity-questions

Comment: Because techno music rocks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a sort of celebration:

> The road from jetty to the city was clogged with people in a celebratory mood. Loud speakers–giant black boxes decked on mini-trucks–blared loud and shrieking music on a road filled with revelers dancing wildly. [Source](http://www.paintedstork.com/blog/tag/mandalay)

However there are extremely few sources online or even none that give any answers as to what, so this is the best I can give. Even though the author saw this in Mandalay, it seems to happen throughout Myanmar, especially since the description exactly matches yours.